# Expand width of circle

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-shapes

I'm pretty new to CSS3 animations to I'd like to know you how to do the following one:
I have a circe:

[image: CSS circle]

On hover, I'd like to **expand the width of the circle** making it into a pill shape with a transition like in this image:

[image: CSS circle with expanded width]

This is what I tried. The issue is that the circle transitions to an ellipse as the width expands :

```css
.logo {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.logo:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to change the border-radius value to any other unit than percentage (all units listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)). For an explanation of how this works and why you need to use these units for the desired output, see [Border-radius in percentage (%) vs pixels (px)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-vs-pixels-px).

Example with px. **The circle expands to a pill shape** on hover :

```css
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.logo:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

If you don't know the height of the circle, you can set a very high value so the circle keeps its pill shape as the width expands :

```css
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.logo:hover {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: simple and brilliant +1

Comment: If the size is unknown, using a big unit (like `in`) may produce a bigger length with a smaller number.