# Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px) or em

Tags: css, css-shapes

If I use a **pixel or em value** for border-radius, the edge radius is always a **circular arc** or a **pill shape** even if the value is greater than the largest side of the element.

When I use **percentages**, the edge radius is elliptic and starts at the middle of each side of the element resulting in an **oval or ellipse shape** :

[image: pixel (px) border radius][image: percent (%) border-radius]

Pixel value for border-radius :

```css
div {
   background: teal;
   border-radius: 999px;
   width: 230px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 40px 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: courier;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<div>border-radius:999px;</div>
```

Percent value for border-radius :

```css
div {
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  padding:40px 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:courier;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div>border-radius:50%;</div>
```

Why doesn't border radius in percentages act the same way as border-radius set with pixel or em values?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

### Border-radius :

First, you need to understand that the border-radius property takes 2 values. These values are the radii on the X/Y axis of a quarter ellipse defining the shape of the corner.
If only one of the values is set then the second value is equal to the first one.
So `border-radius: x;` is equivalent to `border-radius: x/x;`.

### Percentage values

Referring to the W3C specs : [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3 border-radius property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-border/#the-border-radius) this is what we can read concerning percentage values:

> Percentages:  Refer to corresponding dimension of the border box.

So `border-radius: 50%;` defines the radii of the ellipse this way :

- the radii on the **X axis** is 50% of the containers **width**
- the radii on the **Y axis** is 50% of the containers **height**

[image: Border-radius in percentage (%) make an ellipsis]

### Pixel and other units

Using **one value** other than a percentage for border radius (em, in, viewport related units, cm...) will always result in an ellipse with the same X/Y radii. **In other words, a circle**.

When you set `border-radius: 999px;` the radii of the circle should be 999px. **But** another [rule is applied when the curves overlap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-border/#corner-overlap) reducing the radii of the circle to half the size of the smallest side. So in your example it is equal to half the height of the element : 50px.

[image: Border-radius in pixels (px) make a pill shape]

---

For this example (with a fixed size element) you can obtain the same result with both px and percentages. As the element is `230px x 100px`, `border-radius: 50%;` is equivalent to `border-radius: 115px/50px;` (50% of both sides) :

```css
.percent {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.pixels {
  border-radius: 115px/50px;
}

/* For the demo : */
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="percent">border-radius: 50%;</div>
<div class="pixels">border-radius: 115px/50px;</div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  It's a pity that percentage radius values are calculated separately for width and height.  It means that I can't get circular corners that scale with the size of the object, without knowing the aspect ratio of the object.  Wouldn't it be nice if the percentage applied to the larger of the objects dimensions?

Comment: @ChrisDennis That isn't true. Like OP said, you can simply use `border-radius: 999px;`. That way you get your circular corners and be sure that they scale with your element

Comment: But I might not want semi-circular ends to the box. I'd like to be able to specify x-radius as, say, 10% of the box's width and y-radius equal to x-radius.

Comment: Hey did you do other self answered post like this ? I'd appreciate reading those.

Comment: But what actually works with percentage is: `border-radius: 50%/100%` (Tested in Chrome 60 + 61)

Comment: @denns `border-radius: 50%/100%` works on Firefox too! I tested on Firefox 58.

Comment: You can use `vw` or `vh` instead of percentage when trying to refer to a percent of the width or the height respectively.

Comment: For percentage units, i read somewhere that max is 50%; if you use 60% or 1000% it acts like 50%; what about for absolute px units, what's the max that can be used ?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this about just setting a border radius that's super big, so that it shows two semi-circles at the shortest/narrowest edge. Amazing!

Answer (score 8):

a way to get it properly scaling to the viewport size, but staying rounded without any js, would be to do:

```
border-radius: 3vmin;
```

then it will always scale to the smallest dimension, so you will never have a box with semicircular sides, and you don't need any js to calculate the correct percentages.

**edit:** sorry, forgot `vmin` existed, so changed it to use that instead.

Comment: Note:  The vmin unit is 1% of the viewport's smaller dimension.  So in the example above, that would be 3% .

Comment: you can even use this technique with clamp like `border-radius: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 3rem)` if you want to set minimum and maximum values to your border radius. And use whatever unit is the most fitting in the context (vw, vh, vmin, vmax etc)

Answer (score 3):

Just divide the first value by the % you want.. so if you want a border-radius of 50%, write:

```
border-radius: 25%/50%;
```

or another example:

```
border-radius: 15%/30%;
```

You can easily do the math in js or SASS.

Comment: Isn't that just 25% of the width and 50% of the height? That's not the same thing as 50% of the height in both X and Y directions.

Comment: I don't know what kind of math you've been doing, but it's not "just math". It's a specially-defined shorthand for border-radius that has nothing at all to do with arithmetic division. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-radius

Answer (score 0):

1. If the height of the container is defined, we can make it half of the defined height.
2. If the container has a single line of text, like chip, border-raidus of 1.2em would do it.
3. If the height is dynamic, I guess there is no straight or css only way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).