# Round edges on shorter side in CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to make my text input have rounded edges on the shorter side, which is vertical side. The effect I need looks like this:

[image: border-radius: 9999px;]

If I use `border-radius: 50%;`, which makes corders fully round, I get this:

[image: border-radius: 50%;]

The effect I need can be achieved by providing some random large number to `border-radius` and this is what I did: `border-radius: 9999px;`.

Is there any better way, which doesn't involve fake numbers?

Comment: I think the perfcet number is 1/2 height of the box.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to make it height independent.

Comment: You should have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px). It is very much related and would give you details on why the fake number works but not 50%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a huge number, e.g.

```css
border-radius: 9999999px;
```

```css
.horizontal {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
}
.vertical {
  width: 50px;
  height: 175px;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 9999999px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal box"></div>
<div class="vertical box"></div>
```

It works because, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-overlap),

> Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent
>   border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs must
>   proportionally reduce the used values of all border radii until none
>   of them overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with:

```
border-radius: 15px;
```

If you get Inspect Element open you can modify the values to see which looks best without having to edit the code on the server

Answer (score 0):

The best, easiest, and most straight-forward method is to use a border-radius in pixels that's exactly half the height of the box.

```
box {
    border-radius: __px /* Half Box Height */;
}
```

But, if you need to use dynamic values that don't rely on fixed pixels, there's always a way for that too.

```
box:after, box:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: __px /* Box Height */;
    z-index: 1;
}
box:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
box:after {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
box {
    position: relative;
}
```

There's also an experimental CSS feature called `calc()`. In the future, you might achieve this by `calc()`-ing the percent into pixels.

CSS rule `border-radius: calc(0px+100%);` will work, only after `calc()` has been fully developed. That rule will convert `100%` into pixel-units.

You can also set the `border-radius` to `9999px` or any very large number of pixels, although this "trick" may not be cross-browser compatible. According to the CSS specification...

> Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs must proportionally reduce the used values of all border radii until none of them overlap.

Comment: Thanks for an awesome answer, but I'd like to use something more simple. It seems like there's no better way than my multiple 9s at the moment.

Comment: Actually, 9999px might be cross-browser incompatible. Who knows what other browsers will think of 9999px?

Comment: @NarawaGames 9999px is perfectly acceptable, see [oriol's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30990847/4639281)