# Can I make an ellipse using the CSS border-radius property?

Tags: html, image, css, border, css-shapes

I'm trying to make a rectangular image (headshot)

```
width: 200px;   
height: 280px;
```

display as an ellipse.

I can't seem to stop it trying to make a circle, or forming points at top and bottom, while the sides are still flat.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As explained in [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29966499/1811992) you can use `border-radius:50%;`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-radius), the individual `border-radius` properties accept a second value which if not specified defaults to whatever the first value is.

> #### 3.3 The 'border-radius' properties
>
> The two length values of the 'border-radius' properties define the radii of a quarter ellipse that defines the shape of the corner (see the diagram below). The first value is the horizontal radius (or vertical if the 'writing-mode' is vertical). If the second length is omitted it is equal to the first (and the corner is thus a quarter circle). If either length is zero, the corner is square, not rounded. The border radius also causes the element's background to be rounded (even if the border is 'none'). Negative values are not allowed.
>
> [image: Image from the specification]

You can use this to specify exactly where you want the radius to occur:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;   
  height: 280px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 25%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

An ellipse would use `100%` for either the first or second value, but a value less than `100%` for the other:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;   
  height: 280px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25% 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25% 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25% 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 25% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Fallback for clip-path !! Thank you for the reply !! Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you really tryed something ??

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 280px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```