# Does CSS border-radius x y exists?

Tags: css

Let's say we have simple div and his width != height.

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

and css looks like:

```css
#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30%;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

[image]

The `border-radius` in percentage makes longer side more curved. This value in `px` would make border equally curved:

```css
#test{
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

[image]

My question is, is there a way (using CSS) to manipulate this proportion in `px` (independent from changing div size) and make for example shorter side of div more curved? Or it's only achievable via canvas.

Comment: This should help : [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29966499/1811992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two values with a slash in between if you want all rounded corners look the same, or you can use selectors for the single corners and use two values without a slash to get independent results for each corner, like `border-top-left-radius: 45px 80px;`

Here are three examples (I added a symmetric one, similar to the one in your question):

```css
.x {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 45px / 80px;
}
.y {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 45px 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 125px 60px;
}
.z {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px 65px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px 65px;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px 65px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
<div class="z"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Writing this question I found the answer:
[CSS PIE support](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius)

It is possible by using slash between values:

```
border-radius: 10px / 30px;
```

[image]