# Element with border-radius and different radii does not render properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "tag"-like element where the radii of the borders are different on the left side.

```
border-radius: 50px; /* for a completely rounded right side */
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
```

Here's a very brief example:

```css
.tag {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="tag">Jeanne Oliver</span>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwytekLr/5/)

The problem: the two corners on the left, where I should have 3px rounded corners, don't seem to have any rounding at all (see it in the fiddle)

**Possible starting point**
I've noticed that if I reduce the larger radius to something like `10-12px` the issue stops manifesting.

However I don't understand **WHY** this is happening, and also I need the larger number because the code needs to be used on a variety of tag sizes and don't want to rewrite the border-radius for each size.

Comment: This might be relevant: "Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs must proportionally reduce the used values of all border radii until none of them overlap..." --[w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap). Also see the information at [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px) or em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px-or-em#answer-29966500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when 2 adjacent corners exceed the size of the border box (in your case it's 50px top-right and 50px bottom-right, which exceeds the element's dimenions) and the browser has to scale down **all** border radius until they won't intersect.

More details on [www.w3.org - corner-overlap](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap) and a better exemplification [here](https://youtu.be/JSaMl2OKjfQ?t=1m20s) (Lea Verou, "The Humble Border-Radius")

Answer (score 0):

left radius is applied, nothing is going wrong - you can check it by setting     `display: inline-block; height: 200px;` to span. 3px is very small radius to make visible effect on your original span size.

Comment: That is incorrect. As I mentioned in the question, if I set the general radius to something like `border-radius: 12px` the 3px rounded corners on the left do get rendered properly.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting effect. Did you noticed that `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-top-left-radius` don't overwrite previously set  `border-radius: 50px`? I've checked css docs and found that you can apply something like this: `border-bottom-left-radius: 50px 20px;`. So in you case it seems you get combined effect. You can see it when remove general radius property (50px)