# How to make a div rounded only from right and left?

Tags: html, css

I want to round left and right side of the button like below

[image]

Notice that its straight line from top and bottom and only rounded from both sides.

```css
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>View All</button>
```

I have tried to use `border-radius:50%` but it made the whole button rounded.

Comment: Border-radius 50% makes whole border radius. So you have to make border radius specific pixels like my code.

Comment: I encountered this issue the other day as well haha, this explains it: [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px) or em](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29966499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this.

```css
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>View All</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a different border radius for the left/right side's of the div.

Try:

```css
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 10%/50%;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>View All</button>
```

And experiment with variations of `border-radius: 10%/50%` like `border-radius: 20%/40%`...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify each of the four corners radius with two percentages, ie:  `top-left`, `bottom-left`, `top-right` & `bottom-right`. One for each corners horizontal and vertical semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipse.

```css
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius:  17.5% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 17.5% 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 17.5% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 17.5% 50%;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<button>View All</button>
```

See the following Mozilla article for further explanation: [MDN: border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)