# How do I make perfectly curved buttons using html and less/css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button perfectly curved using only less/css and html, but I can't figure out how to make it perfectly curved instead of that ugly html (my opinion) curve.

## How I'm Doing It:

### HTML

```
<div class = "scrollToTop">
    <button>up top</button>
</div>
```

### LESS/CSS

`@fullred: #FF0000;`

```css
.scrollToTop button {
.scrollToTop a button {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: @fullred;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 7%;
  margin: 1%;
}

}
```

**What am I doing *wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

Use same width and height values and then adjust the border-radius as per your smoothess taste.. perfered border-radius should be between 8-12%

Answer (score -1):

Its easier to define border-radius in pixels. As explained here [Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px) or em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px-or-em) defining border-radius in % might give unexpected results.