# How to code a perfect circle on the email page html?

Tags: css, email, geometry, padding

```
                            <div style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;text-align:center;background-color:#ffffff">
<div style="height:20px;"></div>

<div style="margin:0 auto; max-width: 350px; border: none;">
    {logo}
</div>

<div style="height:20px;"></div

<div style="padding: 150px 40px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#fde45f;width:600px;max-width:100%;border-radius: 50%;">
    <p style="text-align:middle;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;">
        <b>Hello {first_name}</b>,
```

#Currently the circle is not perfect, and the shape of the circle changes in every devices' email. I want the text perfectly inside the circle. I don't know why the circle shape keeps changing on the email page.

Comment: Border radius property takes two values. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966499/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixels-px-or-em

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;text-align:center;background-color:#ffffff">
        <div style="height:20px;"></div>

        <div style="margin:0 auto; max-width: 350px; border: none;">
            {logo}
        </div>

        <div style="height:20px;"></div>

      <div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: #fde45f;    width: 600px;    border-radius: 100%;    height: 600px;    display: flex;    align-items: center;    justify-content: center;">
          <p style="text-align:middle;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;">
              <b>Hello {first_name}</b></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks fine in window but it seems like it looks oval on mobile email app. Do I have to make a separate code for the mobile?

Comment: yes you could add separate code for mobile device.